# How do I Prevent Beachball in Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run various subprocesses in Python, but I always get a beachball.

I have a Menu in Tkinter from where I select, via a button, which process to run. Nevertheless, regardless of the process I choose I am just getting a beachball and the menu freezes.

```
# Import Libraries
import sys
import pandas as pd
import time
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk


# Initialize tkinter
window = tk.Tk()
# Set window title
window.wm_title("")
window.geometry("600x800")

# Create Title
label_a = tk.Label(master=window, text="IM Web Scarper", fg="black", bg="light green", height=2, width=15,
                   relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
label_a.place(x=225, y=10)


# Label color run/success or error
def scrape_label(color, y_coord):
    # Create frame color indicates running and success
    label_scraper = tk.Label(master=window, text="", bg=color, height=1, width=4, relief=tk.GROOVE,
                             borderwidth=3)
    label_scraper.place(x=350, y=y_coord)


# Exit GUI
def click_exit_button():
    exit()


# Run Stock Scraper after button pressed
def run_stock_scraper():
    print("\n Scraper Running")
    process_stock_scrape = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "stock_scrape.py"])
    process_stock_scrape.wait()
    error_code = process_stock_scrape.returncode

    if error_code == 0:
        print("Process OK, return code = 0")
        scrape_label("green", 150)

    else:
        print("Process crashed, return code =", error_code)
        print(process_stock_scrape.stderr)
        scrape_label("red", 150)

    return error_code


# Run Stock Sort after button pressed
def run_stock_sort():
    print("\n Running Stock Sort")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "stock_sort.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 200)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 200)
        print("error")
    return


# Run SPD Prices after button pressed
def run_spd_prices():
    print("\n Running SPD Price Retrieve")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "spd_prices.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 250)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 250)
        print("error")
    return


# Run WEI Prices after button pressed
def run_wei_prices():
    print("\n Running WEI Price Retrieve")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "wei_prices.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 300)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 300)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Cat Scrape after button pressed
def run_cat_scrape():
    print("\n Running Category Scrape")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "cat_scrape.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 350)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 350)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Img Scrape after button pressed
def run_img_scrape():
    print("\n Running Image Scrape")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "img_scrape.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 400)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 400)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Desc Scrape after button pressed
def run_desc_scrape():
    print("\n Running Description Scrape")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "desc_scrape.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 450)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 450)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Price Calculation button pressed
def run_price_calc():
    print("\n Running Price Calculation")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "price_calc.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 500)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 500)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Shipping Data Fix after button pressed
def run_ship_data():
    print("\n Running Ship Data Fix")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "ship_data.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 550)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 550)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Category Fix after button pressed
def run_cat_fix():
    print("\n Running Category Fix")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "cat_fix.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 600)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 600)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Table Merge after button pressed
def run_merge_table():
    print("\n Running Table Merge")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "merge_table.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 650)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 650)
        print("error")
    return


# Run Stock Sort 2 after button pressed
def run_stock_sort_2():
    print("\n Running Stock Sort Final")
    try:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "stock_sort_2.py"])
        scrape_label("green", 700)
    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 700)
        print("error")
    return


# Runs all other scripts
def inventory_logic():
    try:
        run_stock_sort()
        time.sleep(2)

        # Import CSV missing data
        print("\n Determine Missing Data")
        data_df = pd.read_csv('/Users/manuel/Desktop/PCMaxx DB/LIVE_DATA/missing_data/missing_data.csv')
        data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
        print(data_df)
        data_list = data_df['missing_data'].to_list()
        # print(data_list)
        desc_data = data_list[0]
        cat_data = data_list[1]
        img_data = data_list[2]
        prc_data = data_list[3]
        # print(desc_data, cat_data, img_data, prc_data)

        if prc_data > 0:
            run_spd_prices()
            time.sleep(2)
            run_wei_prices()
            time.sleep(2)
            run_price_calc()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("No new prices")

        if cat_data > 0:
            run_cat_scrape()
            time.sleep(2)
            run_cat_fix()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("No new categories")


        if img_data > 0:
            run_img_scrape()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("No new images")

        if desc_data > 0:
            run_desc_scrape()
            time.sleep(2)
            run_ship_data()
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("No new descriptions")

        if desc_data or img_data or cat_data > 0:
            run_merge_table()
            time.sleep(2)

        run_stock_sort_2()
        print("Finished Process")

    except Exception:
        scrape_label("red", 75)

    return


# Run Stock Sort 2 after button pressed
def run_inventory_scraper():
    print("Running Main Inventory Scraper")
    # Clear labels
    scrape_label("white", 150)
    scrape_label("white", 200)
    scrape_label("white", 250)
    scrape_label("white", 300)
    scrape_label("white", 350)
    scrape_label("white", 400)
    scrape_label("white", 450)
    scrape_label("white", 500)
    scrape_label("white", 550)
    scrape_label("white", 600)
    scrape_label("white", 650)
    scrape_label("white", 700)

    # Run Inventory logic
    try:
        scrape_error = run_stock_scraper()
        print(scrape_error)
        time.sleep(2)
        if scrape_error == "0":
            inventory_logic()
        elif scrape_error == "1":
            print("houston we have a problem")
            exit()
    except Exception:
        print("Exception error")


# Create Main Run Button, link it to run_inventory_scrape()
web_scraper_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Main Inventory Scraper", fg="blue", bg="light blue",
                               command=run_inventory_scraper, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
web_scraper_button.place(x=150, y=75)


# Create button, link it to click_Exit_Button()
exitButton = tk.Button(window, text="Exit", height=2, width=5, fg="red", bg="yellow", command=click_exit_button,
                       relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
exitButton.place(x=50, y=30)

# Create Stock Scraper Button, link it to run_stock_scraper()
web_scraper_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Stock Scraper", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                               command=run_stock_scraper, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
web_scraper_button.place(x=150, y=150)

# Create Stock Sort Button, link it to run_stock_sort()
stock_sort_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Stock Sort", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                              command=run_stock_sort, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
stock_sort_button.place(x=150, y=200)

# Create SPD Prices Retrieval Button, link it to run_SPD_prices()
SPD_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run SPD Prices", fg="green", bg="light blue", command=run_spd_prices,
                       relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
SPD_button.place(x=150, y=250)

# Create WEI Prices Retrieval Button, link it to run_WEI_prices()
WEI_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run WEI Prices", fg="green", bg="light blue", command=run_wei_prices,
                       relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
WEI_button.place(x=150, y=300)

# Create Category Scraper Button, link it to run_cat_scrape()
cat_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Category Scrape", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                       command=run_cat_scrape, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
cat_button.place(x=150, y=350)

# Create Image Scraper Button, link it to run_img_scrape()
img_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Image Scrape", fg="green", bg="light blue", command=run_img_scrape,
                       relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
img_button.place(x=150, y=400)

# Create Description Scraper Button, link it to run_desc_scrape()
desc_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Description Scrape", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                        command=run_desc_scrape, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
desc_button.place(x=150, y=450)

# Create Price Calculation Button, link it to run_price_calc()
price_calc_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Price Calculation", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                              command=run_price_calc, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
price_calc_button.place(x=150, y=500)

# Create Shipping Data Button, link it to run_ship_data()
ship_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Ship Data Fix", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                        command=run_ship_data, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
ship_button.place(x=150, y=550)

# Create Category Fix Button, link it to run_cat_fix()
cat_fix_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Category Fix", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                           command=run_cat_fix, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
cat_fix_button.place(x=150, y=600)

# Create Merge Table Button, link it to run_merge_tables()
merge_table_button = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Merge Table", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                               command=run_merge_table, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
merge_table_button.place(x=150, y=650)

# Create Stock Sort Button, link it to run_stock_sort_2()
stock_sort_button_2 = tk.Button(height=2, width=20, text="Run Final Stock Sort", fg="green", bg="light blue",
                                command=run_stock_sort_2, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
stock_sort_button_2.place(x=150, y=700)


# Run Inventory Scrape
# Show window
window.mainloop()


# Run Clock
# app = tk.(window)
# window.wm_title("Tkinter clock")
# window.geometry("50x50")
# window.after(1000, app.update_clock)


# Text entry
# new_label = tk.Label(text="Text entry")
# entry = tk.Entry()
# new_label.pack()
# entry.pack()

# retrieve = ""
# while retrieve == "":
# retrieve = entry.get()

# print(retrieve)

# print("retrieved")
# entry.insert(0, "hola")

# text_box = tk.Text()
# text_box.pack()

# frame = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=3)
# frame.pack()
```

This is the code I am running, I have been trying to use try, except and other ways of managing to run this code without my menu getting frozen.

What I wish to do is get the subprocess running, and while it runs be able to press other buttons and run different things. If the subprocess that is running for some reason runs into an exception, I would like to get the code, and text for the exception and have it on screen ( BTW I am using Pycharm), all this while I am still being able to access my Tkinter menu.

Any help is welcome,

Thanks

Manolo

Comment: There isn't a lot we can do since you didn't tell us anything about the tkinter code, which is where the problem is actually happening.  However, I have a suspicion: if the code you show is an tkinter event handler (i.e., if it runs in response to a menu selection), when you `wait()` on the subprocess it will block the tk event loop.  The application will freeze, just as you describe, until the process returns.  There are ways to fix this, but unless you show us the relevant code we can't be much more specific.

Comment: By the way, I've been programming for about 40 years but I have no idea what you mean by "getting a beachball."

Comment: All the script is 385 lines long, there is no wait() as it also freezes my GUI,  by beachball I mean the frozen or waiting icon used by MacOS.  I will try and paste it on the here somehow.

Comment: Your run_stock_scraper functions does call a function named wait().  run_stock_scaper is a tk event handler.  Whenever a tk event handler runs, it blocks all user interface activity until it returns.  Tk can only do one thing at a time, and if it's handling one event it cannot simultaneously handle another.  Other event handlers call time.sleep(), which will have a similar effect since they prevent the event handler from returning quickly.  The result is exactly what you're describing: the application freezes for a while, and doesn't continue until the event handler returns.

Comment: Thanks Paul that solved the freezing (beachball problem) now I have other problems !!! LOL, I have a section that marks the button as correctly run code (green) or exception (red), but as it calls the subprocess the script keeps going and simply marks it red.  I will now have some fun debugging the rest of the code.  Thanks for your help !!